# how to add hover effect over image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my html code? how can we add hover effect to an image?

```
<div class="top-destination">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h3>TOP DESTINATION</h3>
    <div class="images">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-6  col-sm-12  hidden-xs text">
          <img src="images/buddha.jpg" alt="buddha" class="small-image1">
          <h5>Buddha Point</h5>
          <p>Buddha Dordenma<br></p>
          <button>Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you be more specify? where's your css?

Comment: Your question clearly indicates that you haven't done anything for your code to run as per your need. Keep in mind that here at **SO** before asking any que you need to at least create a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) or [**create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to someone to provide you any help.

Comment: You haven't said what the hover effect should be nor what you have tried to accomplish this. Voting to close.

Comment: here is my css and i want >Buddha Dordenma and read more to get appear only after when mouse ia pointed. here is my css code.

Answer (score -1):

just add

```
.small-image1:hover { 
  //add properties
}
```

Comment: i want to make Buddha Dordenma and read more to get appear only after the mouse is pointed on the image and also the outline bos to appear.

Answer (score -1):

use the events onmouseenter and onmouseleave to execute a java function wich handles the effect

Answer (score -1):

Check this link, they have working example for image hover.

https://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/ZYNOBZ

HTML

```
<h1>CSS Image Hover Effects</h1>
    <p>← <a href="http://www.nxworld.net/tips/css-image-hover-effects.html" target="_blank">View the article</a></p>

    <h2>No Effect</h2>
    <div class="column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo01">1. Zoom In #1</h2>
    <div class="hover01 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo02">2. Zoom In #2</h2>
    <div class="hover02 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo03">3. Zoom Out #1</h2>
    <div class="hover03 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo04">4. Zoom Out #2</h2>
    <div class="hover04 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo05">5. Slide</h2>
    <div class="hover05 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo06">6. Rotate<span>(+Zoom Out)</span></h2>
    <div class="hover06 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo07">7. Blur</h2>
    <div class="hover07 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo08">8. Gray Scale</h2>
    <div class="hover08 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo09">9. Sepia</h2>
    <div class="hover09 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo10">10. Blur + Gray Scale</h2>
    <div class="hover10 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo11">11. Opacity #1</h2>
    <div class="hover11 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo12">12. Opacity #2</h2>
    <div class="hover12 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure style="background-color:#9b59b6;"><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure style="background-color:#3498db;"><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo13">13. Flashing</h2>
    <div class="hover13 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo14">14. Shine</h2>
    <div class="hover14 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="demo15">15. Circle</h2>
    <div class="hover15 column">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic02.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
            <span>Hover</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);
body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1,
h1+p {
    margin: 30px 15px 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1+p a {
    color: #333;
}
h1+p a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
    margin: 60px 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h2 span {
    margin-left: 1em;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 85%;
}
.column {
    margin: 15px 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.column:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.column::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.column div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 0;
}
.column div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.column div span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
figure {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
figure:hover+span {
    bottom: -36px;
    opacity: 1;
}



/* Zoom In #1 */
.hover01 figure img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover01 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

/* Zoom In #2 */
.hover02 figure img {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover02 figure:hover img {
    width: 350px;
}

/* Zoom Out #1 */
.hover03 figure img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover03 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

/* Zoom Out #2 */
.hover04 figure img {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover04 figure:hover img {
    width: 300px;
}

/* Slide */
.hover05 figure img {
    margin-left: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover05 figure:hover img {
    margin-left: 0;
}

/* Rotate */
.hover06 figure img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.4);
    transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover06 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(0) scale(1);
}

/* Blur */
.hover07 figure img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover07 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
}

/* Gray Scale */
.hover08 figure img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover08 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: grayscale(0);
}

/* Sepia */
.hover09 figure img {
    -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
    filter: sepia(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover09 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: sepia(0);
    filter: sepia(0);
}

/* Blur + Gray Scale */
.hover10 figure img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
    filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover10 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(3px);
    filter: grayscale(100%) blur(3px);
}

/* Opacity #1 */
.hover11 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover11 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}

/* Opacity #2 */
.hover12 figure {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.hover12 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover12 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}

/* Flashing */
.hover13 figure:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: flash 1.5s;
    animation: flash 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity: .4;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity: .4;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Shine */
.hover14 figure {
    position: relative;
}
.hover14 figure::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -75%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 100%);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
.hover14 figure:hover::before {
    -webkit-animation: shine .75s;
    animation: shine .75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
    100% {
        left: 125%;
    }
}
@keyframes shine {
    100% {
        left: 125%;
    }
}

/* Circle */
.hover15 figure {
    position: relative;
}
.hover15 figure::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
}
.hover15 figure:hover::before {
    -webkit-animation: circle .75s;
    animation: circle .75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 200%;
        height: 200%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes circle {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 200%;
        height: 200%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: added a codepen.io link with it. working example explain more.

Answer (score -1):

> .small-image1:hover{
>   opacity:0.5;
>   }